# Поиск в таблице

Tags: delphi, sql

Есть таблица вида:

```
CREATE TABLE [main] (
  [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  [n_doc] VARCHAR(8), 
  [dat_doc] date, 
  [dat_edit] date, 
  [note] VARCHAR(1000));
```

Надо осуществить поиск по трем полям: `[n_doc]`, `[dat_doc]`, `[note]`. Т.е. есть три поля ввода, в которые вводятся параметры поиска. Они не все могут быть заполнены. Если не заполнено какое-то из полей ввода параметра, то надо исключить его из поиска.
Результатом поиска должен быть переход на найденную строку таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

А в чем проблема-то? Составляйте предложение WHERE, склеивая отдельные его части, в зависимости от того, пустое поле поиска или заполненное, а потом включайте его в запрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select * from main');
if Edit1.text<>'' then
begin
   ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Where (n_doc='+#39+Edit1.text+#39+')')
   if Edit2.text<>'' then
   begin
      ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('and (dat_doc='+#39+Edit2.text+#39+')')
      if Edit3.text<>'' then
         ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('and (note='+#39+Edit3.text+#39+')');       
   end
   else 
     if Edit3.text<>'' then
        ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('and (note='+#39+Edit3.text+#39+')');

end
else
     if Edit2.text<>'' then
        ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Where (dat_doc='+#39+Edit2.text+#39+')')
     else
       if Edit3.text<>'' then
          ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Where (note='+#39+Edit3.text+#39+')');
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте одну индекс для `[n_doc], [dat_doc], [note]`. И через этот индекс ищите, что надо.